# slug not auto generate after add page in django

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-models

I tried to add page for posts blog article for my django site.But it's slug model is not autogenerate after add it into the add post page but it work well in admin page.

example in title field when i type how to master python fastly it will auto generated in slug field with "-" in only admin page.but when I type same thing on add post page it won't generate slug automatically.

mycode

models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django_summernote.fields import SummernoteTextField
from django.urls import reverse
from django.template.defaultfilters import slugify

STATUS = (
    (0,"Draft"),
    (1,"Publish")
)
 
class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200, unique=True)
    title_type = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=200, unique=True)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete= models.CASCADE,related_name='blog_posts')
    updated_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now= True)
    content = SummernoteTextField(blank=True, null=True)
    created_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    status = models.IntegerField(choices=STATUS, default=0)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='images',null=True, blank=True)


    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-created_on']

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.slug = slugify(self.title)
        super(Post, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('home')
```

views.py

```
class AddPostView(CreateView):
    model = Post
    form_class = PostForm
    template_name = 'add_post.html'
```

admin page
[image]

And add post page
[image]

Comment: It is because django admin has some JS written to dynamically update field value as you type. If you want that functionality you might need to write some JS but why exactly do you want slug field to be seen by users?

Comment: As was mentioned above one option is to implement `slugify` functionality yourself in JS in order to get similar behavior as in django admin. Also, while you set slug during saving `self.slug = slugify(self.title)`, you can remove slug field from your UI and rely on the value generated during saving of the model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The slug field should not be editable, remove the 'slug' field from the fields of AddPostView and of the Admin.

```
class AddPostView(CreateView):
    model = Post
    fields = ['title', 'title_type', 'author', 'updated_on', 'content', 
              'created_on', 'status', 'image']
    form_class = PostForm
    template_name = 'add_post.html'
```